# Add range time to the next code

Tags: php, datetime

I've the next code:

```
<?php $date = time();

$contestStart = strtotime('2017-12-31 15:38');

if ($date < $contestStart) { ?>

<html>    VER </html>

<?php exit; } ?>
```

It show text (VER) at day 31/12/2017 at time 15:38, and after this time, text hidden.

I want add a range time, like, start day 2017-12-31 15:38 and end day 2018-01-01 19:00.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you answer me with solution please?
I tryed a lot if codes, but any don't work

Comment: :P why not? If you've solution...?

Comment: I don't understand :( 
I'm bad with english, can you send a code solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `start_date` and `end_date` to `timestamps` using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and then compare them to the current date:

```
<?php 

    $date = time();

    $start_date = strtotime('2017-12-31 15:38');

    $end_date = strtotime('2018-01-01 19:00');

    if ($date >= $start_date && $date <= $end_date) { ?>

    ...
```

Comment: That's because the current given date is between `2017-12-31 15:38` and `2017-12-31 17:15`, do `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";` to see what the current date represent in php

Comment: Issue fixed :P Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

now I've the next code:

```
<?php 

    $date = time();

    $start_date = strtotime('2017-12-31 15:38');

    $end_date = strtotime('2017-12-31 17:15');

    if ($date >= $start_date && $date <= $end_date) { ?>

<html>    VER </html>

<?php   } else {  ?> 
<html>    NO VER </html> 
<?php } ?>
```

but after time 2017-12-31 17:15, persist appear text "VER".

Solution?